# Poor performance thinkpad E550

Tags: performance

Hi I have just bought a lenovo thinkpad E550, and installed Ubuntu 14.04 onto it but I am running into major performance issues. Like 8 + seconds to launch any application from startup, Firefox runs incredibly slow it won't run a video smoothly. The hardware is certified to work with Ubuntu (my exact spec)

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201411-16167/

I have tried changing between integrated Intel graphics and the amd card.

Changing CPU setting in BIOS.

Installed preload and prelink

I have done all updates to drivers and tried changing graphics drivers.

The laptop has a broad well i7, 8gb of ram I don't think it should be as slow as it is any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Lewis

grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo

cpu MHz     : 2400.093
cpu MHz     : 2404.312
cpu MHz     : 2594.250
cpu MHz     : 2472.187

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor

performance
performance
performance
performance

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver

intel_pstate
intel_pstate
intel_pstate
intel_pstate

lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5021]
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo

Comment: Is there any process maxing out the CPU or the RAM?

Comment: Which graphics drivers do you use? Please post the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`.

Comment: I am looking for sufferers of a very specific severe computer slow down issue, in order to acquire supporting data/evidence for the theory as to the root of the problem. Has your LapTop ever suspended since boot? Please provide the results for `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` and `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo`. For the last one, do it while the computer is under some load.

Comment: `preload` can cause significant load on a computer. `prelink`, I don't know.

Comment: Posted answers to your questions in my post above.